# How to send an email notification to admin while creating Opportunity in Professional edition?

Tags: email, notification, professional-edition

One of my client is using Professional Edition. They have given us a requirement for sending an automatic Email Notification, when a new opportunity is created an email should go to their admin with the details of Opportunity.

In Enterprise Edition we can achieve this using Workflow rule and Triggers. But In professional Edition the features are not available.

For time being, I have created one email template and asked them to click Send an Email button which is available in Activity History and then select an Email template which is created by me to send the email. This is working fine. But they feel it more like manual process, they want the automatic one.

Can anyone please help me out in this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Professional Edition doesn't have workflows or automated emails, so your Send an Email button is the wisest choice. You could make that slightly faster by creating a custom email button that auto-selects the email template.

Comment: Thanks Marina. I will speak to my client and try to implement this.